# Segfault from NSLog?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, segmentation-fault

I'm seeing a segfault from using NSLog and specifically, it is on a 64 bit device, with a `SEGV_ACCERR`. I'm new to iOS, so i'm a little confused.

Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x108074000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib             0x00000001826ea31c _platform_memmove + 300
1   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x00000001825289a4 asl_string_append_no_encoding_len + 92
2   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x0000000182522fc8 asl_string_new + 108
3   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x0000000182522df4 asl_msg_to_string_raw + 68
4   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x00000001825228dc _asl_send_message + 828
5   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x00000001825224fc asl_send + 8
6   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182a6fa1c __CFLogCString + 568
7   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182a6f7ac _CFLogvEx2 + 300
8   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182a6fc14 _CFLogvEx3 + 152
9   Foundation                           0x0000000183435dd8 _NSLogv + 128
10  Foundation                           0x000000018336ae04 NSLog + 28
```

Here is the code that calls this:

```
    NSString *truncated = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer];
    // Using original NSLog to print.
    #undef NSLog
            NSLog(@"%@", truncated);
```

and it crashes from my `NSLog` call.

where `buffer` is just a char buffer.

My questions specifically are:

1. Is it even possible to crash from using Apple's provided `NSLog`? Or is my stack trace wrong?
2. What does `SEG_ACCERR` even mean in this context?
3. How could i go about finding if this was caused by a bad memory issue or not?
4. Is something blowing up with the asl file under multiple threads?
5. How should i approach debugging this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the buffer is invalid, for example, not UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

You say that buffer is a char buffer. If that is the case, you should initialize the string like this

> NSString *truncated = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer
>   length:len NSUTF8StringEncoding];

where len is the length of the characters in the buffer.